# Two column (both scrollable) layout messed up in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout such that each of the columns are scrollable seperately. Problem is the width of each column is completely messed up between firefox and chrome. Firefox has like 40px less width than chrome in columns which is causing problems. I'm new to css html please help me out :

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
}

#toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    color: #F3F3F3;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 38px;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#content #left-section {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(29, 29, 29);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width:40%;
    padding: 15px;
}
#content #right-section {
    position: absolute;  
    background: rgb(231, 231, 231);  
    padding:15px;
    width:58%;
    right: 0;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  overflow: auto;  };
}
```

Here's the HTML skeleton:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="toolbar">
       </div>
       <div id="content">
            <div id="left-section">
            </div>
            <div id="right-section">
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a problem:

```
content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I think you have to do :

```
#content {
...
```

Comment: Oh sorry. That was a mistake in my copying. I've edited. Its not the problem.